# How to update content daily in my app without asking user to download and update daily?

Tags: android

My app is kind of information app, so I have to update it regularly. But, if I will do this then it won't be convenient for the user to download or update it regularly. How to update it daily without users permission?

```
 <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="1.LUNCH- Rajma Chawl,Beans,Halwa,Raita,Roti."//want to update this section
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="58dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="2.Dinner- Rajma Chawl,Beans,Halwa,Raita,Roti."//want to update this section
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="58dp" />
```

I have to update this XML file regularly.

Comment: This question is far too broad, but what you really need is to separate your UI from the data. Put your information in a database, write a web service / API layer over that, host it all somewhere that is accessible over the Internet, and then hook your UI up to the service. You update the data in your database, all your users see the changes without having to download a new application. If the data is small/simple enough, you could just put the information you need in an XML/JSON/text file hosted somewhere on the Internet, and update your app to read from that file.

Comment: sry bt i didnt understand

Comment: There is something called as SyncAdapter. You should try to use it.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/index.html check this guide for further information.

Answer (score 0):

You can make auto update , you must do update in background process.. Do services. Make some statement to check daily then do the services in background.

Comment: but how to do that

Comment: Please note that we would rather posters used real words here. Your English does not have to be perfect, but if words like "you" is too much trouble to type, Stack Overflow may not be for you.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake. Thanks for your advise